# JQueryUI AutoComplete - Random Div is added

Tags: .net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So I'm developing a autocomplete textbox using JQuery UI, and .net MVC, It works for the most part. However, when you select a suggested option, a random div with the suggestion is added onto the page, as well as the textbox being completed.

Heres my code:

```
    @ModelType Test
@Code
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
    ViewBag.Title = "asdasd"
End Code

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Test/Search",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: function (resultsCount) { }
            }
        });
    })
</script>  

<div class="">
   @Using Html.BeginForm("AuthenticateStage1", "Authentication")
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @<div class="form-group">

            @Html.EditorFor(Function(x) x.Search)

    </div>
   End Using
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like in the browser: http://prntscr.com/f8u7d1 That is when I hover one of the suggestions.

So, to clarify, why is the div in the left corner being created? and how can I stop it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a broken version of JQueryUI.